# Why is superuser moderated so strictly?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Had this already yesterday with two questions which were "pulled". For one I could even understand it.

Today (just now) the question here

https://superuser.com/questions/252728/library-loading-order

... disappeared while I was typing my answer.

What exactly was wrong with the question? Even though it was about a particular program which exhibited the behavior thanks to loader configuration, the use of environment variables to control the loader and figuring out loader issues is of value to more than the poster of the question. Is it not?

Here's the answer I was preparing so far:

See: http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux (or `man ld.so`)

Use the environment variables `LD_DEBUG` and `LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT` to write a log file with the details of which lib was picked for which symbols.

Comment: Which 2 questions are you referring to? The linked question was deleted by the person who posted thequestion

Comment: @Sathya: I didn't realize, thanks for the clarification. I cannot recall exact topic titles or links from the two topics yesterday, just the surprise when I ended up on the "landing page" ... ;)

Comment: no problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question you quote has been removed and can only be seen by mods and/or 10k+ user, and therefore I cannot answer your specific reason as to why THAT question was closed, but I can answer your general question "Why is Super User moderated so strictly?"

Stack Exchange is a place where one comes to learn and share knowledge.  Super User (one of the first three site on SE) is specifically designed for:

> computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - a shopping or buying recommendation

*straight from [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq)*

Super User is not alone, as [ALL Stack Exchange sites are moderated very, very strictly](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). The reasoning behind this is the fact that we do not want to become another low-quality Q/A site or forum (which SE is not).  This site is meant to be kept clean, clear, and open to everyone.  With these goals in mind it is absolutely essential to moderate each site strictly.

When asking a question on Super User or any other Stack Exchange site, here are some guidelines:

- **Make sure that the question fits within the bound of the sites** [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq).  Failure to do so will cause your question to more than likely be close.  I suggest to ALL new users to browse a little and look at the type of question being asked
- **Make sure that your question hasn't been already answered here**.  There are over [70,000 questions](https://superuser.com/questions) already asked here on SU.  More than likely, your question may have already been asked, and we don't want to be [answering the same questions over and over again.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)
- **When asking a question be clear, precise, and give as much detail as you can**.   Content is HUGE here at SE.  This is why higher rep users can and will edit content [within other user's questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/the-pee-wee-herman-rule/).
- **Shopping recommendations are absolutely not permitted here**.... let me say this again... SHOPPING RECOMMENDATIONS ARE ABSOLUTELY NOT PERMITTED HERE.  If you have a question about something that you want to purchase, consider instead asking questions that prompt [gain of knowledge](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).  [For example](https://superuser.com/questions/203186/laptop-battery-technology).
- **Finally is your question something that will bring good, and new content to the site**.  Yes, there is no such thing as a stupid question, but there is such a thing as a [simple question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/).

Answer (score 9):

Since you are not referencing the 2 from yesterday I cannot comment. However the one you linked too was removed by the owner, not by a moderator.

In general, the whole of Stack Exchange has quite a high expectation of quality for both answers and questions, and recently a review system was put in place to ensure that we meet the standard of quality.

Super User itself is heavily moderator due to the diverse audience and topic. We will not become another forum, and therefore ensure that the level and quality of content is extremely high.

Comment: @Diago: what do you mean by "We will not become another forum"? This and the other stackexchange sites are each a "forum" in the original sense.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED - Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, not a forum

Comment: @Sathya: 1.) where people gather there is a "forum" and 2.) your statement is somewhat in contradiction to the FAQ entry quoted by KronoS (other answer): "The reasoning behind this is the fact that we do not want to become another low-quality Q/A site or forum."

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED A "forum" for me would be a place for extended discussions - something which Stack Exchange is not. I don't see how mentioning Stack Exchange is a Q&A site is a contradiction to to "we do not want to become another [..] forum" - Stack Exchange was not designed/meant as a forum and neither do we want it to go that route

Comment: @Sathya: intentionally left out the "Q/A" part from the sentence in your quote? ;) ... I think the emphasis was on "low-quality" in that sentence. I could also quote it like so: "we do not want to become another [..] Q/A site [..]" ;) So you don't want it to be a bulletin board, is that what it means? The word forum may be misplaced here, because the original meaning and the acquired meaning in IT diverge somewhat (at least that's how I perceive it).

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED it was intentional, since I was focusing on replying to your initial comment where you asked Diago "what do you mean by we will not become another forum". But I see that you get the gist of it - in essence, Stack Exchange does not wish to become yet another Q&A site with low quality answers, neither do we wish (new)users to see pages & pages of "this does not work for me!!!!!111". For discussions, you could always join us in [Chat](http://chat.superuser.com) :)

Comment: @Sathya: thanks. Concerning chat I'll join when I find some more time to actually pay attention ;)

Answer (score 6):

One other point I would like to remind people of is that the Stack Exchange sites are community based participation and management.  Trusted and High reputation users can edit most content on the website.

From the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

> Other people can edit my stuff?!
>
> Like Wikipedia, this site is collaboratively edited, and all edits are tracked. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your questions and answers being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

Beyond editing, anyone with enough reputation can participate in the voting for removing, closing, migrating, flagging, and modification of questions/answers.  Moderators ♦ are not the only people who will close and modify content.

The meta sites are the appropriate sites to discuss site issues, concerns, and questions.  With any issue presented, examples are greatly appreciated to have to some reference for explanation.  The chat rooms generally have a couple active users in them that will help with any questions also at any particular time in the day.

Comment: @Troggy: since you are emphasizing the "editing stuff". I don't have a problem with this per-se. I do have a problem that there is no way to see the revision history, however. Or is this yet another feature one only gets to see after so-and-so many reputation points? Hell, there have been even instances when I would have liked to see revisions of own answers which I edited ...

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED you can view the edit history of your own questions and answers that are edited no matter what.

Comment: @KronoS: Thanks. How about answers I edited (or even those others edited)?

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Yes you can.  I just double checked by logging out, and was able to view all edit histories.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Under any question or answer that is edited, you will see "edited Month X at 00:00".  Click that date and it will take you to the revision page.

Comment: @Troggy: thanks for the hint. Now I got it. Oh yeah, and the obligatory +1 from me (forgot before).